# Trying to get the location of my GPS but the serial received 0.00000;0.00000

Tags: arduino, gps, arduino-uno

[image]

Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
//long   lat,lon; // create variable for latitude and longitude object
float lat,lon ; // create variable for latitude and longitude object
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(3,4);//rx,tx

TinyGPS gps; // create gps object
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600); // connect serial
Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");
gpsSerial.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor

}

void loop(){


String latitude = String(lat,6);
String longitude = String(lon,6);
Serial.println(latitude+";"+longitude);
delay(1000);

}
```

I'm trying to get the location of my GPS but the serial received 0.00000;0.00000 what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check out the example code that come from the TinyGPS library? how do you get the lat and lon if you didn't read any data from gpsSerial?

Comment: Global variables are initialized with 0, lat and lon are never modified. Converting them to Strings is just nonsense, `Serial.print(lat,6);` would do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a big issue, you never get the data from your GPS object into your variables. Do is as follows:

```
// create variable for latitude and longitude object
 double lat = 0; // The lib defines it as double!
 double lon = 0; // The lib defines it as double!
unsigned long lastGpsCheck = 0;
const unsigned long delayTime = 1000;
....

void loop(){
// Replaces the CPU stopping delay, does the same without blocking
 if(millis() - lastGpsCheck > delayTime) {
   lat = gps.location.lat(); // This is missing in your code
   lon = gps.location.lon(); // This is missing in your code

   Serial.println( lat,6 );
   Serial.print(";");
   Serial.print(lon,6 );
   lastGpsCkeck = millis();
  }
}
```

Notice: I replaced the delay, learn early to never use delay in loop, subroutines or libraries. Its ok in setup for waiting for hardware to initialize or as a temporary debug help.
Avoid converting to String class. Always use fix char arrays. String class has bad memory mgmt and fractures your heap (memory leaks -> crash), fix char arrays are compiled to flash.